# how do I use my machine learning model as an api?

Tags: python, api, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

Suppose I created a machine learning prediction model on a data set, I trained it, got some results and now I want to use it to make prediction on some new data which I take from a user. Every one says to deploy it to AWS, Microsoft Azure etc, but I just want to use it for my research purpose, how can I create a simple API of my machine learning model?

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is a bit too broad but I want to share my experience on building my first API in Python.

I installed Flask and a framework on top of Flask called [Flask-RESTful](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.5/).

flask_restful is super easy to use and the official guide helped me out a lot.

My suggestion is to build the API first then figure out which platform you want to use for deployment.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So should I build an API by dumping my model using joblib.dump() method and accessing it by using API?

Comment: What I did is `pickle` the model and `unpickle` the model for the use of the API. I have no experience on `joblib` so I can't say which is better. What I can use is use the libraries that you are comfortable with and work on the improvements from there.

Comment: `joblib` is straight from `scikit-learn` and it handles `numpy` arrays more efficiently than `pickle`. Not to say you can't still use `pickle`, though.

Comment: @Jon Thanks for sharing this! I will check out `joblib` when I have time.